# Managed Package License and Access

Tags: apex, managed-package

Just a quick sanity check:

1. Managed Package is installed
2. NOT a site license
3. A single user has been assigned a license and is writing a VF page and Apex Class

Am I correct in that it is normal behavior to be able to create a VF page that any user without a license can interact with the managed package via the apex controller?

For example, adding input fields bound to controller properties that a controller method uses to set value on the managed object and fields.

In my tests for our package this seems to work and is a bit concerning since it essentially allows clients to bypass the package licensing (albeit with a bit of work)....

I assume this is because Apex has access to all object and as long as the package is active it works.

If the above is true, would the best way to solve this issue as a managed package provider, be to explicitly check for a license assigned to the current user or use describe to check access tot he object(s)

...

Comment: What exactly are you trying to "solve"? Being able to read values from custom fields/objects, or preventing DML?

Comment: Being able to restrict access package fields without a license. It is not a site license.